# Create multipart http post

Tags: http, playback, multipartform-data

I have a visual program with which I am trying to create a http multipart post.
I have two context variables that contain, respectively, a string and a file.
The visual program consists of header and body,detached. In the header i insert
Content-Type multipart/form-data,but how can insert the variabile in the body and how can i indicate the different part the body and her name,how can insert in the header?

Comment: If you would like to get help with your problem, you're going to have to provide more information than this.

Answer (score 2):

Your request could be formed as follows:

```
POST /your_page.html HTTP/1.1
Host: your.host.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=My_Boundary_1234567890
Content-Length: [length of request in bytes]

--My_Boundary_1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MyVariableName"

my_valiable_value
--My_Boundary_1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MyFile"; filename="picture.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

binary contents of the file
--My_Boundary_1234567890--
```

Just do not forget about new line after the last boundary.